# How to write a collapsible directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I know that there is a collapsible directive availble as part of UI Bootstrap, but I would like to create my own one (for the sake of learning how to write directives ;-)).

Now I have a little conceptual problem.

In the end, what I would like to have is something such as:

```
<collapsible collapsed>
  <title>foo</title>
  <body>
    [...]
  </body>
</collapsible>
```

The directive should create the component and show it. So far, so good. What I do not get is how to access the two contained parts `title` and `body`. I have seen that there is `ng-transclude`, but this returns the complete content.

What if I have two separate contents, as given in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate contents implies that you have to access / modify the DOM from your directive.

A few hints (no complete solution, since you want to "write your own" ;)

- You will write a link function in your directive, with scope and  element as parameters.

  > ```
  > link:  function(scope, element) { ... }
  > ```
- You will use $watch to know when you must hide / show your *body* tag.
- You will use angular.element to add and remove a class on your *body* tag and show or hide it.

You can also check the video 25 about angular.element on [egghead.io](http://egghead.io). Not the exact solution to your problem, but somewhat similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some simple jQuery methods to traverse the dom inside of `$element`, however you will not be listening for changes, so if this content is changed asynchronously, your widget will (probably) not reflect these changes.

Instead, you may be better off doing $compile manually for each property (custom ng-transclude) and injecting it where you want, but there are so many variables it's hard to give you a concrete answer.